# mongoose not removing objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Folks, for some reason this method is not letting me delete a user by `email`.

I have tested the functions calling this method, and they are in fact being executed....  thoughts?

```
var deleteUser = function (emailAddress, callback) {
    Users.find({ email:emailAddress }).remove( callback );
}
```

all of code:

```
var Users = require('./mongo/users').Users;

var deleteUser = function (emailAddress, callback) {
    Users.find({ email:emailAddress }).remove( callback );
}
```

./mongo/users.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: String,
    uid: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    roles: Array
});

UserSchema.statics.findByEmail = function (email, callback) {
    this.find({
        email: new RegExp(email, 'i')
    },
    callback)
}

var Users = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

module.exports = {
    Users: Users
}
```

Comment: Post the output of just `Users.find({ email:emailAddress })`. More than likely it's simply not finding the document.

Comment: @MartinKonecny when i do the `Users.find({ email:emailAddress }) i dont get the user object back, but the actul method ie finder { _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   { collection:
      { db: [Object],
        collectionName: 'users',
        internalHint: null,
        opts: {},
        slaveOk: false,

Comment: Sorry, I meant check the output to see if the actual document is returned.

Comment: Solved!  Everything above is valid.  One must be cautious when using async.parallel vs async.series when manipulating data :)

Thanks